# Is there a way to add a role to someone without mentioning/pinging them? [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

Pretty much the title. Every time I try adding a role to someone using this:

```
const member = message.author;
member.roles.add('732727208774205460');
```

I end up with this TypeError:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

However, if I use it like this:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
member.roles.add('732727208774205460');
```

It works completely fine. Problem is, that only works if the person I'm adding a role to was mentioned/pinged by the user. I'm trying to add a role to the user *himself* where the user doesn't ping anyone (for censorship, mainly). Is there a way I could do this without getting the TypeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving an error because `message.author.roles` is undefined, so trying to use `.add()` on it causes an error.

`message.author` is of type `User`, which represents a discord user, and is not associated with any particular server.

You're looking instead for `message.member` which has type `GuildMember`, which represents a particular user's profile inside of a guild (`message.member` is just `message.author` but as a `GuildMember` instead of a `User`). It is the `GuildMember` type that has roles.

Solution:

```js
const member = message.member;
member.roles.add('732727208774205460');
```

Official Documentation:
[User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User),
[GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)